# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate#0'

Tags: mysql, spring

I am building a [Project](https://github.com/kaironconsents/kairon) from github. When I build the project on eclipse.

After configuration with my database I get this error.

> Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate#0' defined in ServletContext resource 
>    [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolData
>    Source#82d210' of type [com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource] while setting bean property 'dataSource';
>    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.mysql.jdbc.
>    jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource] for bean with name 'com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolData
>    Source#82d210' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml];
>   nested exception is java.lang.
>    ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean
>   (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Your `pom.xml` contains MySql connector, the error should not occur. How are you running in eclipse?

Comment: Well it is there but with scope provided... Hence it isn't on the class path when running the application as it should be already there because, well provided.

Comment: i am imported the maven project and configured the application context and context.xml. then run maven clean. then run on server. Thank you. it was the my sql connector issue. I added com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar dependency in the pom. now the issue is resolved. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a jar. Please include this jar in your classpath: `com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar`

Comment: That is a bit old isn't it? Download the driver from the MySQL website or use maven to get a correct version.

Comment: Updated to another jar which also includes the required class.